# How to download image from imageuri in android from firebase downloadable uri

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, imageurl

I have the downloadable uri of my image from firebase storage. On click of button I want to download the image to my phone. I have written the full code, but nothing happens on click of it.

I have the image uri in getIntent().getStringExtra("Image")

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              //  new DownloadImage().execute(getIntent().getStringExtra("Image"));

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
                myDir.mkdirs();
                Random generator = new Random();
                int n = 10000;
                n = generator.nextInt(n);
                String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
                File file = new File (myDir, fname);
                if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
                try {
                    Bitmap  bitmap = Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(getIntent().getStringExtra("Image")).asBitmap().into(100, 100).get();
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Some error in console?And you must let it work in IO thread.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your `getIntent().getStringExtra("Image")` has the image Uri you can use:

```
Glide
.with(getApplicationContext())
.load(getIntent().getStringExtra("Image"))
.asBitmap()
.into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(100,100) {
    @Override
    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
        //Now save this resource
    }
});
```

**NOTE:**  In this case the exact size must be provided (anything below 1 isn't accepted)